# Nuxt.js + vue.js Nitro error build production

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, nitro

Im use base app. Nuxt 3 not building production. Reinstall doesn't help =((

```
√ Server built in 504ms                                                                                       13:07:20
√ Generated public .output/public                                                                       nitro 13:07:20
i Building Nitro Server (preset: node-server)                                                           nitro 13:07:20

[nitro 13:07:22]  ERROR  Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, readlink 'F:\my-app\node_modules\node-fetch-native\dist\polyfill.mjs'


undefined


[13:07:22]  ERROR  EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, readlink 'F:\my-app\node_modules\node-fetch-native\dist\polyfill.mjs'
```

Reinstal node, npm.
Clean cache, remove dirs.